# JS between function

Tags: javascript, between

I need help with this between function. My clock here is 24 hours.

I always get the "else" option. What is wrong with the code?

```js
// Get time
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours();
console.log(time); // 8 o clock right now when I am testing

// Between function
Number.prototype.between = function(first, last) {
  return first < last ? this >= first && this <= last : this >= last && this <= first;
};

// Do something
if (time.between(7, 9)) {
  console.log("between(7, 9)",time.between(7, 9))
}
if (time.between(9, 15)) {
  console.log("between(9, 15)",time.between(9, 15))

}
if (time.between(15, 18)) {
  console.log("between(15, 18)",time.between(15, 18))

}

// and so on
else {
  console.log("else")
}
```

Comment: is it 8 at night?

Comment: Sorry, I have 24 hour clock here. So 8 for me is in the morning.

Comment: well ... you said '8 o'clock' without specification

Comment: you get the  if between 7 and 9 AND the else, right? .... you probably want to use if/else if/else if/.../else if/else

Comment: I added more details. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/p0kfgw42/).

Comment: *I always get the "else" option. What is wrong with the code?* How do you know which option you get?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - you have no else - the problem is that there's only an `else` for the last `if` ... so, really OP would get the if between 7 and 9 .. AND the else :p

Comment: I made you a snippet with debugging. You could have done that too

Comment: `Number.prototype.between = function(first, last) {
  return this > first && this < last; /* add = to include first and/or last */
};`

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem "if else".. Easy fix :)

Answer (score 0):

The else only connects the last if. Just write else ifs

```
   // Get time
    var today = new Date();
    var time = today.getHours();
    console.log(time); // 8 o clock right now when I am testing
    
    // Between function
    Number.prototype.between = function(first, last) {
      return first < last ? this >= first && this <= last : this >= last && this <= first;
    };
    
    
    // Do something
    if (time.between(7, 9)) {
      console.log("between(7, 9)",time.between(7, 9))
    }
    else if (time.between(9, 15)) {
      console.log("between(9, 15)",time.between(9, 15))
    
    }
    else if (time.between(15, 18)) {
      console.log("between(15, 18)",time.between(15, 18))
    
    }
    
    // and so on
    else {
      console.log("else")
    }
```